# 9/16 pedals wont go in crank - they're too big

Tags: pedals

What about if you have two gears on the crank. I used a 5/8 open wrench to take out my original pedals on my Schwinn Sierra and the new 9/16 pedals won't go in - they're too big. What size would it need? I'd like to use an adapter.

Answer (score 4):

First verify that you are in fact trying to screw the left pedal into the left crank arm and the right pedal into the right crank arm. The pedals are sometimes marked with a R and L on the end of the threaded section. The left side is the side your left hand is on while riding. There are 2 common size pedal threads. Many children's bikes, some lower cost department store bikes and some folding bikes use 1/2" thread on the pedal . Most others use a 9/16" thread on the pedal. My guess is you bought 9/16" pedals and they are too large to screw in to your crank arms. While they make adapters to use 1/2" pedals in 9/16" holes there is not one for the reverse. As an alternative you can ask your local bike shop to determine if the crank arm has enough material to modify it to the 9/16" thread. This likely more expensive them getting the correct pedals.

Comment: I've seen a few 1/2" to 9/16" adaptors on Amazon and eBay, however they're not that cheap

Comment: The OP is looking for 9/16" pedal to 1/2" crank adapter.

Comment: Sunlite Pedal Extenders - 9/16" Pedal, 1/2" Crank, 19.5mm https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0037N6NCG/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_g6pgDbRVVV63E

Comment: You are correct way more than the cost of getting the  correct pedals

Answer (score 2):

You can't get an adapter to fit a big pin in a small hole, without pushing the pedals farther apart horizontally. To keep the pedals at he same distance, you'd have to drill out the holes to a larger diameter and then rethread them, which probably isn't practical. Just take the pedals back to the shop for a refund and buy pedals in the correct size (which is apparently 1/2in).

Answer (score 2):

9/16" - 1/2" crank adapters can be found online but do work out quite expensive.

[Not an endorsement](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0037N6NCG/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_g6pgDbRVVV63E) but an example of what to search for.

I notice the OP asked for adapters but considering the price and the fact with the adapters fitted your pedals will protrude further than normal, my actual suggestion is what others have said above and replace the pedals for 1/2" pedals to fit your crank.

Answer (score -1):

It's 5/8" pedals .good luck finding them. Mid school mongoose and schwinn used this size pedal for a few bikes and some old school bikes. I have a mongoose crank and I can't find these size pedals anywhere!

Comment: I've never heard of 5/8" pedal threads. That's just not a thing - unlikely you're thinking about 1/2" because that's smaller and would go though a 9/16" bore without touching.  Do you have any further information ?

Comment: Wouldn’t 5/8” be bigger than 9/16”? I don’t see how OP’s pedals can be too big for the crank if supposedly, the correct diameter threads are even wider than the usual 9/16”.

Comment: I'm with Maple It can't be a 5/8" pedal thread if a 9/16" thread is too big for the crank